# Are there wrappers for the Actionscripts's LocalConnection for C# or Java?

Tags: c#, java, flash, actionscript, localconnection

I want to communicate with the LocalConnection framework of Flash via C#/Java/C++. My search for already implemented wrappers was not as successfull as I wish ;). There exist several servers (like FluorineFx) which support binding of C# objects to the LocalConnection. The problem is I am not looking for a server but only for a simple (marshalling of strings is enough) wrapper. After reading the AMF specification that implementing my own wrapper might take some time ;) which leads to my question:

Does anybody knows a simple wrapper (C#/Java/C++) for the LocalConnection framework?

Edit: I am looking for a AMF3 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking I discovered another approach: I build the "client" in ActionScript and use the compiled SWF file on a C# form (via the ActiveX Showckwave player). The client now communicates with the LocalConnection and to the Host (C#) application via ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the server, could you use ExternalInterface to facilitate the communication between Flash/C#? I'm not entirely sure of your requirements, but EI works well between C# and Flash.  It's a fairly easy process, and would allow for the transfer of more than just strings too (should you end up needing it).

Comment: Well, the problem is that the C# part is not the hosting application of the Flash application. Additionally the ExternalInterface is not supported in AIR applications.